# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I get the warning in the title when compiling. I understand that it is about not handling some cases of `if`, but how can I filter before mapping in the correct way?

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.UserReducer.user.employeeInfoList.map(role => {
          if (role.employeeType) this.rolesOfUser.push(role.employeeType);

          if (role.xdockId) this.xdockIdsOfUser.push(role.xdockId);
        });

  }
```

Comment: You should have a default return value for the arrow function. At present your map function returns value for the 2 if conditions. Those loops do not pass the  conditions  will return nothing.

Comment: If you need to perform filter operation use array.filter().

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are misusing `map` which is used for mapping/transforming one array to another. Having a call to `map` without a return value indicates a problem, as you shouldn't be using it to just iterate over an array performing some action.

It looks like what you really wanted was a `forEach` call.

Comment: Thanks for answer, would it create any memory problem? It works the way I want with the code I shared without returning anything. However I am curious about the effects.

Comment: @beqqqqno, not really. But a simple change from `.map` to `.forEach` will solve the warning, and have no side effect to your code

Answer (score 0):

To filter an array use `Array#filter`. Also you can use `Array#forEach` for your case

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.UserReducer.user.employeeInfoList.forEach(role => {
      if (role.employeeType) this.rolesOfUser.push(role.employeeType);

      if (role.xdockId) this.xdockIdsOfUser.push(role.xdockId);
    });
}
```

Or

```
componentDidMount() {
  const rolesOfUser = this.props.UserReducer.user.employeeInfoList.filter(role => {
    return role.employeeType;
  })

  const xdockIdsOfUser = this.props.UserReducer.user.employeeInfoList.filter(role => {
    return role.xdockId;
  })

  // Do smth with both arrays
}
```